# Rails4: How can I change a display position after clicking a link?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, will-paginate, turbolinks

I use `will_paginate` at the bottom of the page.
Although the page is displayed after clicking the page number, the position of a scroll remains the same (bottom of the page).
I'd like to display the top of the page.

How can I change the display position?

\view\calendars\index.html.erb

```
...
<%= will_paginate @calendar %>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript for this

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @RSB. You gave me a clue, but there is a bit of a problem. So I posted [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26447948/rails4-scrolltop-doesnt-work-every-other-click). Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.